# What is the security risk if Ad Hoc Distributed Queries are enabled?

Tags: sql, sql-server, security

Before I ask my boss to enable Ad-Hoc queries, I want to know what I'm asking for.

Every once in a while (at least once a year, but not more than once a month), we get an excel sheet that has information that we need to put in the database.  I'd like to write a stored procedure that takes the path to the spreadsheet as a parameter and does the necessary processing, but when I try to use `OPENROWSET`, I get this error:

`Ad hoc access to OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' has been denied. You must access this provider through a linked server.`

I've done some looking, and it seems that I have two choices:

1. [Add a linked server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306397), which is undesirable because it sounds like I would need to put the excel sheet directly on the machine that is running SQL Server.  I would like anyone on the team to be able to run this process, but not everyone should necessarily have access to the server machine.
2. [Allow Ad-hoc access to the database](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-using-tsql-to-import-excel-data-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/#fourth).  This seems more desirable, but I want to know why Microsoft disables this functionality to begin with before I go asking permission to poke holes in our security.

So, does anyone know what the actual security risk is here, or is it just Microsoft being paranoid?

Comment: For a server to be able to open a spreadsheet from a file path it will need access to that file.  It seems like that means it would need to be on the SQLServer machine regardless - unless you pass the data over the client connection.

Comment: From what I could tell in the documentation I read, there isn't a requirement that the path to the spreadsheet be local to the SQLServer machine.